# Initialize first ajax data with a preset value then pass it from success response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

How can I initialize the `lastID` in jquery only first time with the value **0** because `var lastID = 0;` does not work.

I have this ajax script in index.php

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var lastID = 0;
            function getData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'data.php',
                    data: {lastID: lastID},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        lastID = data[0].id;
                        console.log(lastID);
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                                        $('<td>').text(item.id),
                                        $('<td>').text(item.name),
                                        $('<td>').text(item.details)
                                        ).appendTo('#output');
                            });



                    }
                });
            }


            getData();


            setInterval(function () {
                getData();
            }, 10000);  // it will refresh your data every 10 seconds

        });
    </script>
```

This is the `url: 'data.php'` :

`$sql = "select * from oders where id > ".$lastID." ORDER BY id DESC";
...
echo json_encode($dataArray);`

With this query I get 0 results, and in console (`console.log(lastID);`) I have no data.

If I change the query like this :

`$sql = "select * from oders where id > 0 ORDER BY id DESC";`

In `console.log(lastID);` I get the correct last id. And in html I get the correct data and every 10 seconds it keeps adding same results over and over again.

I can't figure out how to initialize lastID first time as 0 (or the last ID in the database), and on every 10 seconds refresh, take the last ID from the ajax success data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does your `$lastID` variable come from, how is it defined?

It looks like you are not getting the correct value from the `$_GET` array.

What you should do to both solve that problem and the sql injection problem you have, is switch to a prepared statement:

```
$sql = "select * from oders where id > ? ORDER BY id DESC";
```

And bind `$_GET['lastID']` to the placeholder before / during the execution of your query (depending on whether you are using mysqli or PDO).

Comment: I believe you are right thank you. I forgot to bind `$_GET['lastID']`. The code is just for development so don't mind the security issues of the php. One more thing after I added the `$_GET['lastID']` the jquery doesn't refresh with the `setInterval` anymore any ideea why would that be?

Comment: @Victordb Are you sure? Perhaps there are no new records. You should check the browsers javascript console to see what is happening exactly.

Comment: Ah you are right there weren't any new records. I'm dumb sorry :)).